# C# confused about delegates, publishers and subscribers

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Consider the following console program. It has four classes: Program, Attacker, Defender, and Helper. I want to remove the logic from the Defender class and use delegates to call helpers. I've spent some time on this and can't quite get it.

Where do I declare my delegate: in Program or in Defender?
Where do I instantiate my delegate: in Program or in Defender?
Where do I subscribe my delegate: in Program or in Helper?

I could post my attempts but it wouldn't be helpful.

```
using System;

namespace Delegates19
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Attacker a = new Attacker();
            string weapon = "sword";
            a.Attack(weapon);

            Defender d = new Defender();
            d.Help(weapon);

            weapon = "spear";
            a.Attack(weapon);
            d.Help(weapon);
        }
    }
    public class Attacker
    {
        public void Attack(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Attacker attacks with {s}");
        }
    }
    public class Defender
    {
        public void Help(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Defender is attacked with {s} and calls for help");
            if (s == "sword")
                Helper.Knight();
            if (s == "spear")
                Helper.Bowman();
        }
    }
    public class Helper
    {
        public static void Knight()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Knight charges Attacker");
        }
        public static void Bowman()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bowman shoots Attacker");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It´s completely unclear what you want to achieve. Why do you need a delegate? Where should the code from `Defender` go?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to remove the knowledge Defender has of Helper. Defender should ask for help without any knowledge of Helper. Ideally, Defender should be able to report the attack and the method of attack, and the program logic should dynamically assign the appropriate Helper method. If there is a new form of attack, a halberd for example, the Defender shouldn't have to have knowledge of a Helper. Instead, the program logic should designate an appropriate method (maybe Slinger()) to assist the Defender.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why you would want to do this, but these both work and might give you ideas.

Unless I understand your need for events/delegates I actually prefer your code over these.

**Delegates:**

```
public class Defender
{
    private static Action SwordAction = Helper.Knight;
    private static Action SpearAction = Helper.Bowman;

    public void Help(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Defender is attacked with {s} and calls for help");
        if (s == "sword")
            SwordAction();
        if (s == "spear")
            SpearAction();
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static void Knight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Knight charges Attacker");
    }

    public static void Bowman()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Bowman shoots Attacker");
    }
}
```

**Events:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var d = new Defender())
    {
        d.GetHelp += StandardDefenseHelp.Defender_GetHelp;
        d.Help("sword");
        d.Help("spear");
    }
}

public class Defender : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<string> GetHelp;

    private void RaiseGetHelp(string weapon) => GetHelp?.Invoke(this, weapon);

    public void Help(string weapon)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Defender is attacked with {weapon} and calls for help");
        RaiseGetHelp(weapon);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GetHelp = null;
    }
}

public static class StandardDefenseHelp
{
    public static void Defender_GetHelp(object sender, string weapon)
    {
        if (weapon == "sword")
            Knight();
        if (weapon == "spear")
            Bowman();
    }

    private static void Knight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Knight charges Attacker");
    }

    private static void Bowman()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Bowman shoots Attacker");
    }
}
```

**Important:**  events often are the cause of memory leaks, that's why Defender is now disposable.

The above design *could* be useful if you have multiple "DefenseHelp" types and other things also should happen when a defender needs help that the defender itself needs to know nothing about.

But I'd only do this if it gave some benefit.  I believe in the KISS development methodology.

Comment: Thank you. Why? I'm an old school programmer (lots and lots of Perl and a good bit of R) transitioning to Microsoft and C#. First, I've heard how great delegates and events are and want to see for myself.  Second, I seem to be having a good deal of conceptual difficulty overcoming the initial hurdle and see it as another (and much higher) mountain to climb.

Comment: @ccc31807 Can you clarify what you mean by "Why?"  Happy to help if I can get you to where you are trying to go.  Event-based design is best used to decouple things.  But Defender really should control its own logic.  Who better knows how a Defender should act than itself?  FYI, in C# delegates (and events by extension) are multicast.  Which means they can invoke multiple targets.

Comment: @ccc31807 Edited with a somewhat more reasonable event-based design.  Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: To clarify: My first event driven program was in the late 90s, when I was doing a lot of HTML and JavaScript, so I know how to do this in the context of web apps. However, I'm not an OO programmer and I've been exploring SOLID and design patterns. One principle that I have seen repeated is Low Coupling. I've also been told that events and delegates are used to develop programmable objects that have minimal coupling. I'm just trying to figure out how it works. I'm also not a GUI programmer and do not want to do UWP, so I'm sticking with console apps. Which is fine since that's how I did Perl.

Comment: @ccc31807 Don't forget the "S" in SOLID - Single responsibility principle.